# translating an string to dictionary specified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i'm new to python.
i'm trying to translate the message string to dictionary specified
values.
for example the output for 123 should be abc.
my code:
`

```
import string
message = "57669.843.5987945.5464219238.4857.94.297825.123.85427.29.5937.973.82.123.8.75898.94.2985925.89.59.59.9.74224.6844.384765"
parts = message.replace('.', ':').split(':')



l = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
```

`

i tried converting the list to integer but i could not find a solution

Comment: `123 should be abc`: Why not `lc` (12-3) or `aw` (1-23)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
l = dict(zip(range(1,27),string.ascii_lowercase))  # here I have changed the order
print(l)

{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}

message = "57669.843.5987945.5464219238.4857.94.297825.123.85427.29.5937.973.82.123.8.75898.94.2985925.89.59.59.9.74224.6844.384765"

parts = message.replace('.', ':').split(':')

print(parts)
#['57669', '843', '5987945', '5464219238', '4857', '94', '297825', '123', '85427', '29', '5937', '973', '82', '123', '8', '75898', '94', '2985925', '89', '59', '59', '9', '74224', '6844', '384765']


k=[]
for x in parts:
    for y in x:
        k.append(l[int(y)])
''.join(k)

#output
'egffihdceihgideedfdbaibchdhegidbighbeabchedbgbieicgigchbabchgehihidbiheibehieieiigdbbdfhddchdgfe'
```

OR

You can also achieve your exact message transformed by a single for loop:

```
message = "57669.843.5987945.5464219238.4857.94.297825.123.85427.29.5937.973.82.123.8.75898.94.2985925.89.59.59.9.74224.6844.384765"

import string
l = dict(zip(range(1,27),string.ascii_lowercase))
lst=[]
for x in message:
    if x!='.':
        lst.append(l[int(x)])
    else:
        lst.append(x)

print(lst)
'egffi.hdc.eihgide.edfdbaibch.dheg.id.bighbe.abc.hedbg.bi.eicg.igc.hb.abc.h.gehih.id.biheibe.hi.ei.ei.i.gdbbd.fhdd.chdgfe'
```